# Algorithm over 2 pages

Tags: floats, page-breaking, algorithms

I am writing a few rather large pseudocode functions using `algorithm` and `algorithmic`, i.e. my code looks something like:

```
\begin{algorithm}                     
\caption{Coolest Algorithm ever}          
\label{findme}                          
\begin{algorithmic} [1]                   % enter the algorithmic environment
\REQUIRE    Here are a few variables \\
            variable 2 \\
            variable 3 
\ENSURE     this is the output \\
            output 2

\STATE $some cool code here$
\STATE $some cool code here$
\STATE $some cool code here$
\STATE $some cool code here$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Unfortunately this code does not fit on one page and I am definitely not able to split it into some subfunctions or so (I already did that as far as possible).

So now I need to split up the algorithm into two pages, but I have no idea how.

The easiest way I can imagine is just to start a new algorithm on the new page, but this time letting the line counter start at line 35 or so instead of 1. But how can I do that?

Please not that there is already a similar question here on this site, but it deals with the package `algorithmicx`.

Comment: Note that the [`algorthmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) is compatible with the commands provided by `algorithmic` (from the [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms)).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use the [algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package instead and its `\algstore` and `\algrestore` commands. If you don't want to rewrite all your `algorithmic` algorithms, you can still use `algorithmicx` either by loading the `algpseudocode` package with the `compatible` option, or by loading the `algcompatible` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}                     
\caption{Coolest Algorithm ever}          
\label{findme}                          
\begin{algorithmic} [1]                   % enter the algorithmic environment
\REQUIRE    Here are a few variables \\
            variable 2 \\
            variable 3 
\ENSURE     this is the output \\
            output 2
\algstore{myalg}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}                     
\begin{algorithmic} [1]                   % enter the algorithmic environment
\algrestore{myalg}
\STATE $some cool code here$
\STATE $some cool code here$
\STATE $some cool code here$
\STATE $some cool code here$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example output for algorithm over 2 pages]

Comment: I just tried it and got this error: LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'algcompatible' for package 'algpseudocode'. Why that? I use MacTex

Comment: @chris Most probably you are using an outdated version of `algpseudocode` (and possibly some other package(s)). The best way to proceed would be to update your packages or, even better, your LaTeX system. If updating is not an option, you could try with the now superseded option `compatible` instead of `algcompatible`; e.g., `\usepackage[compatible]{algpseudocode}`.

Comment: I just updated my complete system with all packages, the error is still the same - when I use compatible instead of algcompatible, my file compiles, but not all commands are supported

Comment: @chris: my bad. You can use either `\usepackage[compatible]{algpseudocode}` or `\usepackage{algcompatible}`. I mixed the two options up (must be the flu). I will correct my example code.

Comment: Apparently, I am getting error when porting it to `beamer`.

Comment: OK, seems like I need to use `\begin{algorithm}[H]` in `beamer`.