# Avoid multiple occurrence of a multi-page algorithm in the list of algorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms, pseudocode

I have a pseudocode which spreads in multiple pages.

I tried `\algstore` and `\algrestore` (as advised in [Algorithm over 2 pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29816/algorithm-over-2-pages/116961)) and it allows multiple pages but it causes problem with `\listofalgorithms` and it adds one line for each part.

How can I make sure that it just adds for the first part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used `\caption*` for the second occurrence of algorithm block and it is all good now :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}                     
\caption{Algorithm XYZ}          
\label{findme}                          
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Do Something 1
\State Do Something A
\State Do Something B
\State Do Something C
\algstore{myalg}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm} 
\caption*{Algorithm~\ref{findme} Continue ...}
\begin{algorithmic} [1]                  
\algrestore{myalg}
\State Do Something D
\State Do Something E
\State Do Something F
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```