# Long algorithm doesn't split into two pages

Tags: algorithms

I wrote an algorithm but it is long and it can't fit in one page but my problem is that it doesn't split into two page .. what happen is that a part of the algorithm appears in the first page and the rest disappears as shown in the figure below .. any solution?

[image]

and this is the code of the algorithm:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Calculating Score}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{CheckBetaamplitude}{}
\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(1) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(2) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(3) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(4) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(5) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(6) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(7) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(8) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(9) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(10) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(11) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(12) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(13) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(14) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(15) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(16) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(17) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(18) \gets n/length()$

\State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
\State $n \gets length(i)$
\State $s(19) \gets n/length()$


\State $score4 \gets Average(s)$
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: To me this algorithm looks like a loop: `for (j = 1; j < 20; ++j) { i = find(absolute()<maxamp); n = length(i); s(j) = n/length() } score4 = Average(s);`
Of course this doesn't answer your question, but would resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it doesn't work as I didn't add the parameter of the functions .. which is different in each line.

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29816/algorithm-over-2-pages

Comment: Can I have the complete MWE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you go :)

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Calculating Score}\label{euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{CheckBetaamplitude}{}
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(1) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(2) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(3) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(4) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(5) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(6) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(7) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(8) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(9) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(10) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(11) \gets n/length()$
    \EndProcedure
    \algstore{myalg}
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithm}                     
    \begin{algorithmic} [1]              
    \algrestore{myalg}
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(12) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(13) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(14) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(15) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(16) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(17) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(18) \gets n/length()$
    \State $i \gets find(absolute()<maxamp)$
    \State $n \gets length(i)$
    \State $s(19) \gets n/length()$
    \State $score4 \gets Average(s)$
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Hello, in this I face a problem that the text that is written after it goes in front . How to get rid of it.