# Elegant way to break/continue out of a nested loop

Tags: algorithms

When typesetting an algorithm, is there an elegant way to break/continue out of a nested loop. Something [like how it is done in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/loop/nested.html). Any recommendations?

```
\begin{algorithm}
 \texttt{'J:} \For{i = 1,...,n}{
   \For{j = 1,...,m}{
     \If{Something}{
       \KwSty{break} \texttt{'J}
     }
   }
 }
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your snippet is an excerpt of a document that *typesets* a loop, so you can invent whatever you like. In LaTeX loops like `\foreach` there are commands like `\breakforeach`.

Comment: With [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) you can use `\algsave` and `\algrestore`. See [Algorithm over 2 pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29816/5764).