# About pseudo code in algorithm environment

Tags: algorithms

I have used algorithm environment to write pseudo code just like the photo and get some really good result

[image]

and here is the corresponding latex code

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Find the missing number (A, l, r)}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{ModifiedBinarySearch}{$A, r, l$}{
        \State{m$\gets\lfloor\frac{l+r}{2}\rfloor$}
        \If{$r = l$}
            \State\Return{m}
        \ElsIf{$A[m] = m$}
            \State\Call{ModifiedBinarySearch}{A, m + 1, r}
        \ElsIf{$A[m] = m - 1$} 
            \State\Call{ModifiedBinarySearch}{A, l, m \text{-} 1}
            \State\Call{ModifiedBinarySearch}{A, m + 1, r}
        \ElsIf{$A[m] = m - 2$}:
            \State\Call{ModifiedBinarySearch}{A, l, m \text{-} 1}
        \EndIf{}
    }
    \EndFunction{}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

but it will encounter some question that it can not break if there is a new page, so I find something useful called **breakablealgorithm** and the environment setting show below

```
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
  {% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
   \begin{center}
     \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
     \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
     \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
       {\raggedright\textbf{\fname@algorithm~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
       \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
        \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
       \else % #1 is not \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
       \fi
       \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
     }
  }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
     \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
   \end{center}
  }
\makeatother
```

the break was good but there are some indent issue with it like the figure below
[image]

the upper one is normal algorithm environment and the lower one is the breakablealgorithm environment how can I make it more consistent since the breakablealgorithm has a poor format that add some redundant indent

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Consider this: [Algorithm over 2 pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29816/5764) (possible duplicate)